# Why won't eslint-config-rallycoding work with create-react-app?

Tags: atom-editor, eslint, create-react-app

I'm using Atom and the `linter-eslint` npm package. I have installed the following dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^4.9.0",
  "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0"
}
```

This is my `.eslintrc` file in order to use the `eslint-config-rallycoding` eslint rules:

```
{
  "extends": "rallycoding"
}
```

When I open a file, the first line shows this message:

[image]

The `eslint-config-rallycoding` eslint rules work great with the [React/Redux starter set](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter) that the same author made, so I'm thinking something isn't set up right to use with `create-react-app`?

The error message is incredibly vague though and I am not seeing any errors in the specified file.